# Categorical column in to a dummy array in Excel

Tags: excel, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I'm trying to translate a machine-learning model into excel, so that data analysts could play with it interactively.

I'd like to transform a categorical variable into dummy representation:

```
WeekDay
Monday
Thursday
```

to

```
WeekDay
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,1,0,0,0}
```

Using excel arrays.

I tried this:

```
={INT(A1="Monday"),INT(A1="Tuesday"),INT(A1="Wednesday"), ...}
```

However, for some reason, excel doesn't accept forumlas in array expressions.

This approach does work, but it is problematic - since it does not allow combinig multiple arrays into one

```
=IF(A1="Monday", {1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, IF(A1="Tuesday", {0,1,0,0,0,0,0}, ....))
```

Also, it's super ugly

Any ideas ?

Comment: How are you using these arrays?

Comment: Are you trying to use this array in another formula, or in vba? A cell cannot hold an array, it can hold a text string that looks like an array, or a single value, but not an array.

Comment: These arrays would be multiplied with a matrix, with excel's `MATMUL` function - no `vba`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your array you can use INDEX like this:

```
INDEX(IF(TEXT(ROW($2:$8),"dddd")=A1,1,0),0)
```

This returns a vertical array.

to return a horizontal array use:

```
INDEX(IF(TEXT(COLUMN($B:$H),"dddd")=A2,1,0),0)
```

I have spilled the results of the array in the photo below:

[image]

---

If one has the Dynamic Array Formula SEQUENCE the ROW and COLUMN can be replaced with:

```
SEQUENCE(7,,2)
```

and

```
SEQUENCE(,7,2)
```

Respectively

Comment: Thanks, would I be able to combine multiple dummies as well ? e.g. "WeekDay" + "Month" into one big array of size 19 (=7+12) with all zeros except 2 entries ?

Comment: @UriGoren that is a different question than this one.  New questions get new posts.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the end goal is, but I would suggest instead of an array (again, assuming you are not utilizing VBA, and even if you are, this is very possible with Case functions):

Use the formula =Weekday(Cell,different return type for which day should = 1)

If you were to use the actual date (e.g. 5/1/2020), display it through custom formatting with only the day of the week (typically data analysis will already have the full date),

Cell Value A20 = "5/1/2020", format display Long Date - "Friday, May 1, 2020"

cell referencing with formula '=WEEKDAY(A20,1)' = 6

cell referencing with formula '=WEEKDAY(A20,2)' = 5 (is this similar to {0,0,0,0,1,0,0} enough for you to use?)

if using VBA, you could define a range with logic to turn this into {0,0,0,0,1,0,0}

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you wanted Month and Date, using the actual full date value you could combine =Month() with =Weekday(), again if VBA recommend setting two variables (one being monthValue and the other being weekDayValue as Range and then using them to iterate you purposes?

Comment: Also using a statistical analysis software, say MATLAB or Minitab, having a column for months, and a column for weekday you can MANOVA/ANOVA/Regress those for dependencies.

Comment: Of course, you could also read those as TEXT values, and they would still work for the same purpose. (e.g. response optimization indicates either Value = 1 for Weekday, or Value = "Monday" in combination with value = "January", or 1 for monthValue.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `python` to train the model, I want to make the inference possible for users who only have `excel` installed on their machine and have zero interest in learning a new programming language